# Can this regex be simplified? Desired pattern is words with upper case

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following JavaScript regular expression.  I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify or improve it.

Here's my existing RegExp, which doesn't test for new lines, or the beginning of the string:

```
/([^0-9a-z+=%$#?!&<>;()@* -,.\/{}\^\[\]\\]+)$/
```

Here's what I've tried since words are only alphas and underscores, but it says new lines are valid, as are special characters.

```
/\b\w[^a-z0-9\n]+\b/
```

I am trying to have words with only uppercase alphas and underscores, with underscores only after an alpha.

Valid input would be:

```
ERIS_TEST_GROUP_NAME
JENNIFER_AD_GROUP_NAME
PSEUDO_TEST_TEAM
TEST_GROUP
```

Invalid input would be anything with new lines or special characters, lower case characters, or starting with the underscore:

```
    _JEN_TEST_GROUP
    234*((_&&*^
    ab^*(_EWRR)
    e_RERE_^&)(*$#$#@()\\
```

Comment: May be: `/^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$/`

Comment: "Words with uppercase" -> is this valid? 
wordWithuppercase

Comment: Camel case is not valid, in my situation.  It looks like @anubhava's pattern is pretty close to what I need.

Comment: Is `ERIS_TEST_GROUP_NAME_` valid?

Comment: I guess I didn't say so in my example, but I'd like to avoid it.  It was valid in my first pattern, but I don't really want to have trailing underscores.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, I tried /^[A-Z]+?_([A-Z]+?_)*[A-Z]+?$/ which you can see what it matches and what it doesn't at https://regex101.com/r/RDrph9/1

Answer (score 2):

What you have was close,

\w matches just a single character.

If you'd like to match more than one you can do it with '+'

```
/\b\w+[^a-z0-9\n]+\b/
```

[A-Z]+ will match more than one uppercase characters

so you could try something like this:

```
/\b[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*\b/
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at what you tried I think you might want to test an multiline input. If so, you can try:

```
^(?=.)(?:\n?[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*)+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9xA8C/6)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=.)` - Positive lookahead for a character other than newline.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non capture group.

  - `\n?` - An optional newline character.
  - `[A-Z]+` - Any uppercase alpha at least once.
  - `(?:` - Open 2nd non capture group.

    - `_[A-Z]+` - Underscore followed by at least one uppercase alpha.
    - `)*` - Close 2nd non capture group and match it zero or more.
  - `)+` - Close 1st capture group and match at least once.
- `$` - End string anchor.

And if not, then I think you should go with the option mentioned in the comments by @Anubhava

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*(?:\n[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*)*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/x9xA8C/2/)

**Explanation**:

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```